# CoCreateInstance exact match in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, com, interop

I have in-proc (DLL) COM Server, but I settled in to run as DllSurrogate, for this reason from unmanaged code (Delphi) i have:

```
function TComWrapper.GetServer: IUnknown;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(ServerData^.ClassId, nil, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result));
end;
```

from C# am using now:

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll", EntryPoint = "CoCreateInstance", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern UInt32 CoCreateInstance([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rclsid,
   IntPtr pUnkOuter, UInt32 dwClsContext, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);
```

...

```
            UInt32 dwRes = CoCreateInstance(ClassIdGuid,
                                            IntPtr.Zero,
                                            (uint)(CLSCTX.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER), //if OR with CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER then INPROC Server will be created, because of DLL COM Server
                                            IUnknownGuid,
                                            out instance);
```

Above code is unsafe.
Does it exists safe version fro above `CoCreateInstance`?
It seems that `Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't help me. I have to set explicitly running Context (3rd parameter)

Comment: There's nothing unsafe about a proper pinvoke declaration.  Note how you never had to use the *unsafe* keyword anywhere.

Comment: @HansPassant, so that wrapping `CoCreateInstance` in `unsafe{...}` is useless?

Comment: Can you not just run it as a COM Component in your code?

Comment: @ALZ yes. `unsafe` blocks are basically for unsafe pointer manipulation and you're not doing any.

Answer (score 8):

You could also do this:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid(YourGuidGoesHere)]
private class MyClass
{
}
```

and create an instance of the COM Object like this:

```
  IYourInterface myClass = (IYourInterface)(new MyClass());
```

Without using p/invoke.

Comment: What is COM after class keyword?