# CoCreateInstance() in C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com

I am converting a piece of code from c++ to c#, but am unsure how to use CoCreateInstance(). Here is the c++ (this works and is what I want in C#):

```
IComDevice *Device=NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
    __uuidof(ComDevice),
    NULL,
    1,
    IID_IComDevice,
    reinterpret_cast<void **>(&Device)
    );
```

and here is what I thought would work in c#

```
public class Ole32Methods
{
  [DllImport("ole32.Dll")]
  static public extern uint CoCreateInstance(ref Guid clsid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object inner, uint context, ref Guid uuid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);
}
```

And then in main

```
IComDevice Device;
uint duh = 1;
Guid uuid=typeof(ComDevice).GUID;
Guid uuid2 = typeof(IComDevice).GUID;
Ole32Methods.CoCreateInstance(ref uuid, null, duh, ref uuid2, out Device);
```

IComDevice is an interface in a .dll made in c++. I reference it in my C# code. Basically I need this code because I can't call any functions in the interface unless I initialize my Device. CoCreateInstance was doing that in my C++ code. The code I posted doesn't run because it can't use Device as object. I notice that in the C++ code the Device is a pointer, which may be something to implement here. I am just unsure.

UPDATE: I used [CoCreateInstance exact match in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987491/cocreateinstance-exact-match-in-net) to write my code, but his doesn't use an interface, pointers, or reinterpretcast

Comment: Because in the linked question Simon asks very nicely the .NET to load a COM object, and the .NET loads it, hiding all the ugly complexity. You discover what `IID_IComDevice` is and put it in the `[Guid()]`, and then hope :-)

Comment: Simply use `Device = new IComDevice()` in a C# program.

Comment: @HansPassant Cannot create instance of the abstract class or interface IComDevice()

Comment: @xanatos the GUID is accepted but the device is not because it is an interface not an object

Comment: If that fails then the IComDevice interface declaration is missing the [CoClass] attribute.  The one that automatically gets added when you add a reference to the type library of the COM component.  Maybe you are helping too much, do avoid declaring IComDevice yourself.

Comment: Can you post a link to what you are talking about? I don't understand.

Comment: Try: IComDevice Device = new ComDevice()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Some languages (either compiled or scripting) like Visual Basic 6.0, VBA, VBScript, JScript have **runtime that hides activation details of COM objects**. They also check and convert HRESULTS to exceptions. Also they manage lifetime automatically invoking AddRef, Release.
- [here is my steps how to implement simple out of proc COM server and C++ client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104218/1544015)

If you change [out] attributes of parameters to [out, retval] in IDL file of this COM project and rebuild then you can test following (my first C#) code:

```
using System;

using COMStructProviderLib;

namespace CSharpCOMClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IMyStruct mystruct = new MyStruct();
            mystruct.setName("John");
            String name = mystruct.getName();
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            mystruct.setAge(5);
            long age = mystruct.getAge();
            Console.WriteLine(age);
        }
    }
}
```

Please pay attention that after new is **MyStruct - not IMyStruct**. MyStruct is the name indicated in idl file("coclass MyStruct" in my example and can differ not only by prefix I)Also it's required to add reference to registered COM server to C# project (COMStructProviderLib). Also via link mentioned above you can get corresponding C++ COM client and compare with C# client provided here. Please pay attention to comment in C++ client - CoCreateInstance is hidden - it's invoked inside smart pointer initialization.