# Creating an inter-process communication ATL COM component failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, atl

[How COM can be use to transfer Data between two process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096671/how-com-can-be-use-to-transfer-data-between-two-process)

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/cossdk/installing-new-components

Follow Simon Mourier's answer to create an COM+ Application and its Component.
[image]

I choose the 3rd, Install new event class(es).
[image]

select the COM dll.
[image]

**At last, it failed.**

[image]

Comment: Why did you choose "event class"?

Comment: @SimonMourier, at first, I chose the 2nd, But I could't find my compoent in the given list.

Comment: Don't use that. You can choose the 2nd if your component is already registered (regsvr32, etc..) in the same registry (32 vs 64 bit), or choose the 1st and browse to your .dll.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Yes, It works!!!!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I adopted the advice given by @SimonMurier. It worked!
[image]